# Compare values inside same subdocument for findOne() [MongoDB]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have a database full of objects that look ~exactly like this (simplified for clarity):

```
{
    "_id": "GIFT100",
    "price": 100,
    "priceHistory": [
        100, 110
    ],
    "update": 1444183299242
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a query document for MongoJS (or MongoDB and I can figure out the rest) that looks for the fact that *priceHistory[0] < priceHistory[1]*.

I would want my query document to return the above record as a result. Alternatively, I could change my document code to compare *price < priceHistory[0]* but I believe this still leads to the same problem (comparing values inside the same document).

Any help would be appreciated, I've exhausted my Google-foo.

**Edit:**

I want to return a set of records that indicate a price drop since our last scan (performed daily). Basically a set of "sale" items from a data source I don't control.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain the point of this as there is likely a better way. What is it you really want to achieve here by doing this? Note that *"I wan't to compare the price"* is not the clarification we are looking for here, but rather why do you "think" you need to do this, and to what end?

Comment: I want to return a set of records that indicate a price drop since our last scan (performed daily). Basically a set of "sale" items from a data source I don't control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause, but be careful--it's slow, it cannot use your indexes, and it will perform a full table scan. Pass on whatever Javascript you want to use for comparison:

```
db.collection.findOne({$where: "priceHistory[0] < priceHistory[1]"})
```

Additionally, you can skip the `$where` statement if that's the only thing you're querying by:

```
db.collection.findOne("priceHistory[0] < priceHistory[1]")
```

Comment: Excellent. You're right, it's very slow, but it'll do (small db of ~ 1000 items). Thanks for pointing me to $where, I'll make sure to abuse it in the future.